# Как проверить наличие ключа в Bundle

Tags: java, android

Есть две активити. С первой перехожу на вторую, первую финиширую. А с второй перехожу на первую, но особенность в том, что при нажатии той же кнопки в первой активити, она должна финишироваться(не создавать вторую, как в первом случае). У меня есть мысль передавать в Intent какой-либо ключ, и проверять его наличие в первой активити. Как это можно реализовать?
Если использовать такой код, то программа падает с ошибкой java.lang.NullPointerException

```
boolean prev = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("prev", false);
if (!prev){
  mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Или может быть есть другое решение?

Comment: Возможно Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону Фрагментов ? И не надо будет Вам несколько активити.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение:

```
Bundle extars = getIntent().getExtras();
if ((extars != null) && (extars.containsKey("prev"))){
  ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}else {
  mContext.startActivity(intent);
  ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}
```